# How to add reset game with yes or no ? Game Java

Tags: java

I don't know how to add reset game with yes or no input user
I've tried many solutions and it doesn't work.

here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pr16 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = "Stone";
    String b = "Scissors";
    String c = "Paper";
    //a > b
    //b > c
    //c > a

    System.out.println("Player one choose:");

    String x = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Player two choose:");

    String y = in.nextLine();

    String answer = "";

    do {
            if ((x.equalsIgnoreCase(a) && (y.equalsIgnoreCase(b)))) {
                System.out.println("Player one won");
            } else if ((x.equalsIgnoreCase(b) && (y.equalsIgnoreCase(c)))) {
                System.out.println("Player one won");
            } else if ((x.equalsIgnoreCase(c) && (y.equalsIgnoreCase(a)))) {
                System.out.println("Player one won");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Player two won");
            }
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again? YES / NO");
        answer= in.nextLine();
        }

        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")){
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
    }
}
```

any way to add game reset to my code above? any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please refactor names and comments to English : "You want us to give you answers? Then prove that you’ve put some effort into the question, and you can begin by politely asking it in the language this community is formed around." ([source](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = "Stone";
        String b = "Scissors";
        String c = "Paper";
        //a > b
        //b > c
        //c > a
            String answer = "";
        do {
            System.out.println("Player one choose:");

            String x = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Player two choose:");

            String y = in.nextLine();

            answer = "";

            if ((x.equalsIgnoreCase(a) && (y.equalsIgnoreCase(b)))) {
                System.out.println("Player one won");
            } else if ((x.equalsIgnoreCase(b) && (y.equalsIgnoreCase(c)))) {
                System.out.println("Player one won");
            } else if ((x.equalsIgnoreCase(c) && (y.equalsIgnoreCase(a)))) {
                System.out.println("Player one won");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Player two won");
            }
            System.out.println("Do you want to play again? YES / NO");
            answer= in.nextLine();
        }

        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")){
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
    }
```

if you want you can make 2 classes and that will be more cleaner, but this answer will do the job in you main function and no need for other classes